# R ggplot2 geom_line position dodge

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can't find an example on how to do this. I'm trying to draw lines using `geom_line` but dodge the overlapping elements, and it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my data:

```
> sa
    id ep type grp variable value
 1:  1  1 typ1   1       st     1
 2:  1  2 typ1   2       st    60
 3:  1  3 typ1   3       st   120
 4:  1  1 typ2   4       st    20
 5:  1  2 typ2   5       st    60
 6:  2  1 typ1   6       st     1
 7:  2  2 typ1   7       st    80
 8:  2  3 typ1   8       st   170
 9:  2  1 typ2   9       st    10
10:  2  2 typ2  10       st    60
11:  2  3 typ2  11       st   120
12:  1  1 typ1   1       en    50
13:  1  2 typ1   2       en   100
14:  1  3 typ1   3       en   150
15:  1  1 typ2   4       en    40
16:  1  2 typ2   5       en   100
17:  2  1 typ1   6       en    40
18:  2  2 typ1   7       en   150
19:  2  3 typ1   8       en   200
20:  2  1 typ2   9       en    50
21:  2  2 typ2  10       en    90
22:  2  3 typ2  11       en   190
```

Here is my simple code trying to dodge overlapping values for `typ1` and `typ2`

```
 ggplot(sa,aes(x=value,y=id,group=grp,color=type)) + geom_line(size=6,position="dodge")
```

[image: plot I get]

This is what I see. How do I dodge the overlapping bars?

Comment: maybe if you make id a factor, dodge will work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can dodge vertically, but another option is just to add a little dodging yourself. For example:

```
eps = 0.05

ggplot(sa, aes(x=value, y=ifelse(type=="typ1", id + eps, id - eps), 
              group=grp, color=type)) + 
  geom_line(size=6) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=1:2, limits=c(min(sa$id-eps), max(sa$id+eps)))
```

You'll have to play around with the amount of dodging, axis limits, etc., to get the look you want for a given aspect ratio.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can only dodge horizontally, but you can get around this issue by flipping your x and y aesthetics and using `coord_flip`:

```
ggplot(sa, aes(x = id, y = value, group = grp, color = type)) + 
    geom_line(size = 6, position = position_dodge(width = 0.1)) + 
    coord_flip()
```

[image: dodged plot]